# Running a python script within a colab notebook, ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

New to Colab, and I'm trying to reproduce the fine-tuning of a pretrained BERT model in this repository:
https://github.com/ncbi-nlp/ncbi_bluebert

I am trying to run the run_bluebert_ner.py script (from its directory) using this code:

```
!python run_bluebert_ner.py --do_prepare=true \
 --task_name='bc5cdr' \
 --do_train=true \
 --do_eval=true \
 --do_predict=true  \
 --vocab_file=/content/ncbi_bluebert/bluebert_model/vocab.txt \
 --bert_config_file=/content/ncbi_bluebert/bluebert_model/bert_config.json \
 --init_checkpoint=/content/ncbi_bluebert/bluebert_model/bert_model.ckpt.data-00000-of-00001 \
 --data_dir=/content/ncbi_bluebert/data/BC5CDR \
 --num_train_epochs=1.0 \
 --do_lower_case=False \
 --output_dir=output
```

Which gives me this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run_bluebert_ner.py", line 19, in <module>
    from bluebert.conlleval import evaluate, report_notprint
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bluebert'
```

I am able to import and run stuff from bluebert into the notebook itself.

Adding the absolute path of the directory via sys.path.extend does not help.

After searching for a bit, I tried alternately using:

```
%run run_bluebert_ner.py --do_prepare=true \
 --task_name='bc5cdr' \
 --do_train=true \
 --do_eval=true \
 --do_predict=true  \
 --vocab_file=/content/ncbi_bluebert/bluebert_model/vocab.txt \
 --bert_config_file=/content/ncbi_bluebert/bluebert_model/bert_config.json \
 --init_checkpoint=/content/ncbi_bluebert/bluebert_model/bert_model.ckpt.data-00000-of-00001 \
 --data_dir=/content/ncbi_bluebert/data/BC5CDR \
 --num_train_epochs=1.0 \
 --do_lower_case=False \
 --output_dir=output
```

This seems to find bluebert at least, but fails with:

```
AttributeError: only_check_args
```

Deleting all of the flags using FLAGS.**delattr** does not help.

Does anyone have any suggestions?